# How to bypass UnicodeDecodeError in python module, pytds

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2008

The `pytds` module throws the following error when retrieving a certain record from my MSSQL database:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 97: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've found other solutions for fixing this using the `open()` command in Python, but none for the `pytds` module.

Are there any ways to bypass this error or handle it on a per record basis?